# LibGDX Gradle broken build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I updated Android Studio and along with this Gradle to version 5.x. I had to change `desktop.gradle` a bit. 
The build succeeds, but when you run the resulting .jar, crash occurs with an error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:133) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader
    at ru.elvale.amfus.Amfus.initAssets(Amfus.java:99)
    at ru.elvale.amfus.Amfus.create(Amfus.java:45)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

What is more, running `gradlew desktop: run` starts the application successfully.

`desktop.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "java"
sourceCompatibility='1.7'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs=[ "src/" ]
project.ext.mainClassName = "ru.elvale.amfus.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}
task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.generatedSourcesDirs)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.dirs)
    from {configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from files(project.assetsDir)
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
dist.dependsOn classes
```

[image: Files in .jar]

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the libraries, dlls, etc.. that LWJGL uses in the same folder as the jar. Otherwise, you need to pack them inside the jar at build time.

Comment: @Dylan already packed, added a screenshot in the post